# Wpf DataGrid при прокрутке у таблицы закругленные углы становятся квадратными

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

В DataGrid я закруглил углы у строк и шапки с заголовком, но при прокручивание таблицы углы принимают не закругленный вид. Можно как то исправить чтобы углы остались с круглыми краями при прокручивание?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Color_ColumnHeader" Color="Yellow"/> <!--Цвет шапки таблицы-->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Color_MouseOver" Color="Violet"/> <!--Цвет при наведении мыши на строку(item)-->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Color_Selected" Color="BlueViolet"/> <!--Цвет при выборе строки(item)--> 
        

        <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderGripperStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="8"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1 0 0 10"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 0 0 0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Grid>
                            <theme:DataGridHeaderBorder CornerRadius="6" Background="{DynamicResource Color_ColumnHeader}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" IsPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" IsHovered="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" IsClickable="{TemplateBinding CanUserSort}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SortDirection="{TemplateBinding SortDirection}" SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}" SeparatorBrush="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </theme:DataGridHeaderBorder>
                            <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                            <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static DataGrid.FocusBorderBrushKey}"/>
        <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10 0 0 0"/>

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 5"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="YellowGreen" Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" CornerRadius="6" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>
                                <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Color_MouseOver}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource Color_MouseOver}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Color_Selected}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource Color_Selected}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Background="#FF2F5D65">
        <!--<local:ShowNumberControl x:Name="Spisok" ItemsSource="{Binding tests}" DataContext="ss">

        </local:ShowNumberControl>
        <local:CustomTextBox x:Name="CustomTB"></local:CustomTextBox>-->
        <DataGrid BorderBrush="Transparent"  GridLinesVisibility="None" ColumnHeaderHeight="30"  RowHeight="36" Background="#FF2F5D65" RowHeaderWidth="0" CanUserAddRows ="False"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" RowStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridRowStyle1}" CellStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridCellStyle1}" ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1}" x:Name="Table" ItemsSource="{Binding _Grids}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="304" Margin="110,32,0,0">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Phone}" Header="Phone"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Height="36">Delete</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Height="36">Delete</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Height="36">Delete</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Height="36">Delete</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Height="36">Delete</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Height="36">Delete</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Height="36">Delete</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Не думаю, что это возможно, либо легко реализуемо. У вас контент не помещается в заданную рамку, из-за чего рамка вам этот контент обрезает. Скажем так, они остаются закругленными, но только они выходят за пределы видимой области. Чтоб это исправить, надо делать скрол и заголовку, и контенту, не затрагивая "задний фон" и их синхронизировать, либо изобретать другие костыли.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ немного поигрался с таблицей и прочими костылями которые придумал, без результатов. Проще написать свой IteamControl и реализовать дизайн таблицы там. Добавил еще один скрол, он режет заголовок что противоречит виду таблицы https://skr.sh/sL1xu40er4a Лучше напишу свой контрол, легче будет чем переписать таблицу.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Сделал ItemsControl у контента задал скрол. То есть при добавление новых данных, новой строки создается новый скрол, который я устанавливаю как Hidden, также отдельно написал скрол один и подписался на его события чтобы получать позицию для прокрутки, далее перебираю ItemsControl и для скролов у контента устанавливаю новую позицию, получилось достаточно костыльно. Сам код https://pastebin.com/kApaT0Gb может можно кто для ItemControl сделать привязку? Чтобы значения для скролов брались с биндинга или такие костыли лучше не использовать?

Comment: Сделал привязку к модели для ScrolView  может кому пригодится https://stackoverflow.com/a/68320180/13439618 преимущество в том что изменяя значение модели у скролов позиция меняется также, скролы не нужно искать в чем плюс

Comment: @EvgeniyZ протестировал код что выше скинул, лучше подобным не заниматься, при добавление ста строк все хорошо работает, но если добавить 1000 строк то скрол просто напросто пропадает. Как будто там его и не было. Ps у разметки задавал фиксированные размеры, то есть скрол не мог сдвинуться с места